# vmware esxi 6.0 slow disk perfomance

Tags: linux, performance, vmware-vsphere

**Hardware:** Intel SB2600WTTR, 2x Xeon E5-2670v3, 96Gb RAM, 12x Seagate 900Gb 10K in RAID5 (LSI MegaRAID SAS Invader Controller).

**Software:** VMWare vSphere ESXi 6.0.0-20150902001-standard.

**VM:** Debian Linux 8.9 (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64)

Problem is in very slow disk perfomance. `hdparm -tT /dev/sda` says:

```
Timing cached reads:   16950 MB in  2.00 seconds = 8481.87 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 218 MB in  3.45 seconds =  63.11 MB/sec
```

For example, restoring MySQL database using `myloader` gives 7-10 MB/s of disk usage ( `iotop -o` says). Restoring files from tar archive gives similar values (10-12 MB/s). Sometimes VM "stucks" for a minute, with no errors in logs, then resumes file operations.

Found this article: [ESXI 6.5 Storage Performance Issues and Fix | opvizor.com](http://www.opvizor.com/esxi-6-5-storage-performance-issues-and-fix/) - it recommends unload vmware ahci driver. In my case `esxcli software vib list | grep ahci` gives only:

```
sata-ahci 3.0-22vmw.600.1.17.3029758 VMware  VMwareCertified 2017-09-26
```

Created new VM with linux - same result.